# Vertically center a caption to the right of an image using CSS

Tags: css, vertical-alignment, centering

I'm trying to achieve this layout with CSS (without tables, I guess. Whatever). Any ideas?

[image: PUPPY!!]

Comment: I almost wanted to down-vote this question for using Comic Sans. :) http://bancomicsans.com/main/

Comment: yeah, but I think this is done using one of those wireframing tools.. still.. tempting.

Comment: I made it in Balsamiq (and it's Chalkboard, not Comic Sans)

Comment: Looks like Robusto should be down voted for not knowing the difference :)

Comment: My favorite: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KzmrxKhaKRU

Comment: @Mark Quezada: Chalkboard, Comic Sans ... they all drink from the same fount — I mean font. And I'm joking with you.

Comment: @Robusto Haha... hadn't seen that version. Nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few things you can do but it depends on the specifics of the problem. A few questions:

- Is the photo always the same height?
- Is there always only one line of text, or could there be several lines that wrap around?
- Is the text a `block` or `inline` level element?

If the photo is always the same height, and there's only one line of text, you can set the `line-height` of the text equal to the size of the photo and then set the photo to `float:left`.

If there could be several lines of text you might need to use an `inline-block` element and compute the top margin with javascript.

**EDIT:** Unfortunately, this can't be done using CSS alone since there's no vertical centering allowed on block level elements. Here's an example that'll work with any length of text in a `div` along with any size photo: http://jsfiddle.net/W7b4U/39/

**HTML**

```
<img src="http://placehold.it/100x150">
<div class="align">align this  align this  align this  align this  align this  align this  align this  align this  align this  align this  align this  align this  align this  align this  align this  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
img {float: left;}
```

**Javascript/JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $text = $('.align');
    var $img = $('img');
    var margin = ($img.outerHeight() - $text.outerHeight()) / 2;
    var textPadding = 10;
    $text.css({marginTop: margin, marginLeft: $img.outerWidth() + textPadding});
});
```

Comment: Photo isn't always the same height; there could be several wrapped lines; text could be either block or inline (depending on context)

Comment: Check out the above code. Not sure if you're familiar with jQuery or not, but I tried to make it easy to follow. Basically it just calculates the margin needed to center the text on page load. Not optimal, but it works.

Comment: Nice: this is the right behavior. Is it worth using JS for this though? Is there a pure-css version that works on IE7+ / IE8+? Can I achieve this with an inline-block element?

Comment: Unfortunately this can't currently be done with only css because of the lack of vertical-align support on block (and inline-block) level elements. I've looked all over for my own stuff and I always end up resorting to JS because it's the most reliable across browsers. Hope that helps.

Comment: So basically CSS is garbage? Would tables help? ONE MORE QUESTION: suppose the images are always the same size, but the text is variable length (and therefore might wrap). Do I have any CSS-only options in this case?

Comment: No, CSS isn't garbage, this is just one specific case where it's currently hard to do this type of layout. Unless both the text and image are a fixed height, you cannot do this type of layout with only CSS. If they were both a known height (say 50px), you could use `top: 50%` and `margin-top: -25px` which would vertically center the block, but this only works with a known container height.

Answer (score 4):

`Vertical-align:middle` both

http://jsfiddle.net/W7b4U/

Comment: This works as long they're both `inline` level elements and the text won't be longer than a single line.

Comment: Which they are as per his example :)

Comment: i think you only need vertical-align on the image in this case - vertical-align does nothing for the span

Comment: Yea, this is going to get messy if you're using block elements.

Answer (score 1):

Check out **table** and **cell** CSS attributes (especially the elementary case of a table with a single cell whose contents are centered vertically and horizontally).

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#img-cell-align